# How to control access to react native app in local environment

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-go

is it possible to put a password requirement when someone tries to run a react native app using expo developer tools in local environment.

The steps someone would take is:

1. expo start
2. Scan qr code

--- I want to put a password requirement step here---

3. Open app in expo go app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's ready solution for this. I believe you will have to control access inside your app by yourself.

But the thing that is quite similar is publishing your app in expo environment by `expo publish` with `privacy` policy set to `hidden` https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#privacy . Then you could get your QR code by accessing expo link (e.g. https://expo.dev/@community/native-component-list), which would be accessible only for users with right access to your project. More info here https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/publishing/